# Xpages @Dblookup does not work on server

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I write a xpages.

detail： There are two combobox A,B. I use @Dbcolumn on combobox A to get option data from notesview and I will throw the choice I get from A to get second data for B.

the problem is： it work well on my localserver, but get no result on the server.

I'll be very appreciate for any suggestion, thanks you!!

code is on server side as follow：

```
var fd_AppChoice:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspSelectOneMenu = getComponent("fd_AppChoice");
var AppChoice=@Trim(fd_AppChoice.getValue());
var temp=new Array();
temp=@DbLookup("","(A)",AppChoice,2);

return temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

That code doesn't look right - you don't have the server. And defining a variable doesn't fix its data type, so `var temp=new Array();` is irrelevant. I also would rather bind the fd_AppChoice to a scope variable e.g. `viewScope.appChoice`, then your code get easier. Try this:

```
 var appChoice = @Trim(viewScope.appChoice); // Use getComponent.getValue if you have to
 var server = @DbName();
 // if different server or nsf have = ["myserver","mydb.nsf"] or [@DbName()[0],"my.nsf"]
 var result = @DbLookup(server,"(A)",appChoice,2);

 return result || ["Sorry nothing here"]
```

That should work

Comment: so appreciate for your suggestion

Comment: now I change my code as follow,
but still work good on local but return nothing on server 
Keep trying now~ thank you !! :)

var fd_AppChoice:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspSelectOneMenu = getComponent("fd_AppChoice");

 var appChoice = @Trim(fd_AppChoice.getValue()); 
 var server = @DbName();
 var result = @DbLookup(server,"(A)",appChoice,2);

 return result

Comment: I had no idea you could do this -- return result || ["Sorry nothing here"]

Comment: @rrumaner Listen to the "Don't be afraid of curly brackets" recording :-) #TLCC

Comment: @stwissel  sorry~those solution still can't work, any further suggestion?  thank you :)

Comment: Check your code carefully and check your logs. @DbLookup is reliable. Use Print to print all variables to the log. Make sure that the server name resolves properly.

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite confirm this: in my case it works like a charm on my test server (didn't even try locally). Here's my code:

comboBox #1 reads its values from a categorized view of the same database:

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox1" value="#{viewScope.combo1}">
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value>
<![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbColumn(@DbName(), "myView", 1);}]]>
        </xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelC2">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:comboBox>
```

Observe that the combo's onchange event performs a partial update on a panel which is a container for comboBox #2 (could it be that this is missing in your case?)

To get through with this, here's the remainder: combo#2 gets its values array using a @DbLookup which is filtered by the value selected in combo#1, which now is stored in a viewScope variable (how couldn't I agree with Stephan here: using a scope-var make things much easier!):

```
<xp:panel id="panelC2">
    <xp:comboBox id="comboBox2" value="#{viewScope.combo2}">
        <xp:selectItems>
            <xp:this.value>
<![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbLookup(@DbName(), "myView", viewScope.combo1, 5);}]]>
            </xp:this.value>
        </xp:selectItems>
    </xp:comboBox>
</xp:panel>
```

Comment: local side good~but bad on web server 
combobox B keep show nothing~

Comment: <xp:comboBox id="fd_AppChoice"

Comment: value="#{document1.fd_AppChoice}" style="margin-left:0.0%"  
 disableClientSideValidation="true">
 <xp:this.validators>
 <xp:validateRequired>
 <xp:this.message><![CDATA[pls enter apply job[applied job]]]></xp:this.message>
 </xp:validateRequired>
 </xp:this.validators>
 <xp:selectItem itemLabel=" " itemValue="">
 </xp:selectItem>
 <xp:selectItems>
 <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
@Trim(@Unique(@DbColumn("","(A)",1)))}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
<xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
 refreshMode="complete">
 </xp:eventHandler>
 </xp:comboBox>

Comment: <xp:comboBox id="fd_WorkSite"
value="#{document1.fd_WorkSite}"
disableClientSideValidation="true">
<xp:this.validators>
<xp:validateRequired>
<xp:this.message><![CDATA[pls enter[work site]]]></xp:this.message>
</xp:validateRequired>
</xp:this.validators>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel=" " itemValue="">
</xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItems>
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var appChoice = @Trim(getComponent("fd_AppChoice").getValue()); 
 var server = @DbName();
 var result = @DbLookup(server,"(A)",appChoice ,2);

 return result }]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>

Comment: plus~
even though I put the exist value in the @Dblookup like:      var server = @DbName();
 // if different server or nsf have = ["myserver","mydb.nsf"] or [@DbName()[0],"my.nsf"]
 var result = @DbLookup(server,"(A)","programmer",2);

 return result }]]></      it's can't return anything on web server either, but still good on localside